# How to prevent unmounting using React Navigation v6?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a tab navigator filled with many different screen stacks where all of the screen stacks are made up of one screen. Below are two examples in my code. When I do the first one nothing is unmounted. When I do the second one everything is unmounted.

```
// Nothing unmounts
navigation.navigate("TabNavigator", {
screen: "ProfileStack",
params: {
    screen: "ProfileScreen",
    params: {
        userId: user?.userId,
    },
},
});

// Everything unmounts
navigation.push("TabNavigator", {
    screen: "ProfileStack",
    params: {
        screen: "ProfileScreen",
        params: {
            userId: user?.userId,
        },
    },
});
```

I also need to use push() sometimes because if a user is on a profile and then goes to a different profile from there I need them both in the stack so the back button works properly. Why is this happening? What can I do do prevent this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

instead of navigating you can just try reseting your `navigation` `history` as shown below

```
 navigation.dispatch(
          CommonActions.reset({
            index: 1,
            routes: [
              {
                name: TabNavigator,
                state: {
                  routes: [
                    {
                      name: ProfileStack,
                    },
                    {
                      name: ProfileScreen,
                      params: {
                               userId: user?.userId,
                             }
                    },
                  ],
                },
              },
            ],
          }),
        );
```

refer this link for more info
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions/

Comment: This in no way solves the problem